# Is it possible to change view content without performing reload

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create view that contains table with pagination, sorting and search. I'm getting my data from backend api and then I'm passing it to the view.

My action method looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Home(int page = 1)
{
    var list = await _service.Get<List<Model.Rezervacija>>(page);
    ViewBag.Page = page;
    return View(list);
}
```

And I have this view:

```
@using eBiblioteka.Model
@model List<Rezervacija>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<div id="view-all">
  @await Html.PartialAsync("_ViewAll", Model, null)
</div>

<a asp-action="Home" asp-route-page="@(ViewBag.Page - 1)">Previous</a>
<a asp-action="Home" asp-route-page="@(ViewBag.Page + 1)">Next</a>
```

And what view looks like:
[image]

And that all works. Don't pay attention for displaying pages number like this and changing with previous and next, I just wanted to simplify my question. So when i click next page, data changes and table also update very fast and that isn't problem.

But i see in tab that page is reloaded:
[image] .

So is there any solution in asp .net core to do this without seeing that page reload. I need to call my action again to change this param "page" and then fetch new data from api without see that ugly page reload.
Thank you for all solutions.

Comment: Just to check, I see the blazor tag, but are you doing this in blazor?

Either way, if this is normal MVC, unlikely you would be able to avoid the page reloads without using client side code (like javascript) to call the server and update the content on the page.

Comment: Yes, use AJAX. Or perhaps better use Blazor.

Comment: I removed blazor tag, sorry for that. I am not to mutch familiar with .net core mvc. I'm working with react and this is so simple in react. I need to use .net core mvc for this project, so i want to build very good ui and ux...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create view that contains table with pagination, sorting and search without reloading.so you should use jquery for this.update your code like below:-

```
@using eBiblioteka.Model
@model IEnumerable<Rezervacija>

<div>
    <table class="table table-striped border" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.SpecialTagId)
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>  @item.Name </td>
                    <td>  @item.SpecialTag.Name </td>
                    <td>
                        <partial name="_ButtonPartia3" model="@item.Id" /> //you can use partial view for delete or add data.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br /> <br />
@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
       $('#myTable').DataTable();
});

    </script>
}
```

And Add this below link in your _Layout.cshtml:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

And your output will be like this:-

[image]

So when you will go from one page to another page, it will not reload because you used jquery. and it's already sorted and you can also search as needed.

Comment: yeah, i already know about datatable but that isn't server side proccess. I need to call my api to get items for current page, not get all item and then let datatable to do pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some excellent front-end frameworks. I now recommend you use [layui](https://www.layui.com/demo/table/page.html), this is a Chinese community, of course you can also choose other ones. When this layui is paging, the URL is like the following format.

```
https://www.layui.com/demo/table/user/?page=2&limit=10
```

In this way, the .net core api can be called to perform partial refresh without reloading the entire page.

[image]